# site loading issue with some computers

Tags: loading

I have a website that runs just fine with any computer.

But only some of my friends reported a common issue with my website, that it fails to load completely in their computers. In other words, it only loads the site background and doesnt go any further and can't load the body. I just read the source code of the page on those computers and I saw that the `<head>` part of the page was the only thing loaded!

This is strange! Only some of them has this problem not anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is returning a 500 Internal Server error. Your problem is on the server side. Try checking your server logs and see if you can find the probelem

Comment: oh! thats more strange, cause it works here in our country....Does illegal DOCTYPEs can cause such problem?!